# Using RasterResampling with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, resampling

I have a Python application and it uses PyQGIS to - read NetCDF file, convert it to GeoTIFF by writing the rasterlayer with rasterpipe, QgsRasterFileWriter and rasterShader related methods.

However, there is too much pixelization in the TIFF when I zoom in.

```
input_nc_filename = "input.nc"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(input_nc_filename, "east")

resampleFilter = rlayer.resampleFilter()
resampleFilter.setZoomedInResampler(QgsCubicRasterResampler())
resampleFilter.setZoomedOutResampler(QgsCubicRasterResampler())
resampleFilter.setZoomedOutResampler(None)

extent = rlayer.extent()
provider = rlayer.dataProvider()
has_stats = provider.hasStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All)
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, extent, 0)

if has_stats is not False:
    logger.debug("minimumValue = {}".format(stats.minimumValue))
    logger.debug("maximumValue = {}".format(stats.maximumValue))

if stats.minimumValue < 0:
    stats_min = 0
else:
    stats_min = stats.minimumValue
stats_max = stats.maximumValue


width, height = rlayer.width(), rlayer.height()
renderer = rlayer.renderer()
provider = rlayer.dataProvider()

pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())

output_filename = "qgis_cubic.tif"
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(output_filename)

file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, width, height, extent, rlayer.crs())
```

When I tried setting the re-sampling algorithm to Cubic in QGIS desktop application, it worked perfectly.
Now I am trying to do the same in my Python application. I came across few Python classes related to re-sampling -

1. QgsRasterResampleFilter
2. QgsRasterResampler, QgsRasterResamplerV2
3. QgsBilinearRasterResampler, QgsCubicRasterResampler

Unfortunately, I could not get a breakthrough to use these classes while generating the GeoTIFF.
We use GeoTIFF in a webapp developed in Mapbox GL JS and Angular and not in QGIS hosted environment.